# Best way to print your arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have this arrays in my console application code:

```
//multi-dimensional array
int[,] numbers1 = new int[3,2] {{1, 2},{3, 4},{5, 6}};
foreach (int i in numbers1)
      Console.Write("{0} ", i);

//Array-of-arrays (jagged array)
int[][] numbers2 = new int[2][] { new int[] { 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} };
```

I want to find the best way to print them. 
For example I print something like this in my numbers1 array: 1 2 3 4 5 6

And I want to make it look better like this: [[1,2][2,3][4,6]]

Or this: numbers[0,0] = 1, number[0, 1] = 2

I also don't know how to print Array-of-arrys

Any help please?

Comment: This sounds like something that's within your skills to implement yourself. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I want to find best way and learn from others how they do it...

Comment: You won't learn anything unless you actually write your own code.

Comment: Don't you think is better to know first how to write code correctly and then write your own?I think if you learn write bad code is hard to wean latter.

Comment: Regardless, this site is not for code-requests based on vague descriptions with no effort shown. Find a forum or tutorial or something if that's how you want to learn.

Comment: I recommend you try to write a method yourself and post it over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ asking for suggestions on how to improve it.  The people there will be more than happy to rewrite it for you.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff [codereview.se] is for code that works as intended.  This code does not, and we are **not** happy to rewrite people's non-working code for them.  This code would be closed as off-topic on Code Review and we'd recommend the user return here, to [so].

Comment: @nhgrif I meant when the OP had a working sample, not the above code itself.

Comment: "Best" is extremely vague. Best readability? Best execution speed? Best scaling? There's always a multitude of way to do things, the 'best' way is often opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own print method like this:

```
public static void PrintArray(int[,] arrayParam)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< arrayParam.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
         for(int j = 0; j < arrayParam.GetLength(1); j++)
         {
               Console.Write(" numbers[{0}{{1}}] = {2} ", i, j, arrayParam[i, j]);
         }
         Console.WritLine();
    }
}
```